# Delete few records from table whose primary key referencing as foreign key in different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

For Example: I want to delete 2 records from Department table whose Dept_Id is primary key and this is referencing as Foreign key in Employee table. When I tried to delete, it gives error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK__Employee__Dept_I__5CD6CB2B". The conflict occurred in database
>   "CRR_US_Report", table "dbo.Employee", column 'Dept_Id'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the department IDs of the users in yours `Employee` table first. Then perform the delete from the `Department` table.

You have constraint that ensures that each user in the `Employee` table is having a valid department. You want to delete records from the `Department` table that are in use - so, you need to take care about the corresponding records in the `Employee` table first (delete, update, set to NULL if possible).

Answer (score 0):

It is how foreign key works. So foreign key prevents deletion of record if this record is referenced in other tables and guarantees that your employee works in existing `Department`.

So you need edit `IDs` in `Employee` table which referenced by IDs which you want to delete from the `Department` table. And then delete `Department` field.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure, where you want delete the employees for dept that your are deleting

But first you can delete employee  for the dept_id you want to delete then delete the dept_id

Delete from employee where dept_id=
Delete from dept where dept_id=

Hope this helps